# Drupal Commerce 2 Installation

Tags: 8, commerce, drush, composer

I tried to install drupal commerce using following command as described in http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/getting-started/install.html

composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev

but it just shows the following line and stuck for long time

**Loading composer repositorUpdating dependencies (including require-dev)**

atlast I lost connection with my server so I tried again

composer update

but again same result

**Loading composer repositorUpdating dependencies (including require-dev)

Killed**

I want to know if there is anything I am missing ??

Comment: No you're not missing anything, that's the command to run. If you have xdebug enabled, disable it for CLI, composer doesn't like it, but other than that check your network

Comment: where are you from? someone today mentioned that china is apparently blocking composer, maybe its the same for you. packagist also had server issues today, so could have been that. might work now

Comment: It somehow worked when I installed drupal 8 first and then installed drupal commerce 2 separately

Comment: @Clive Note that recent Composer versions disable xdebug automatically, so there's no need to give that advice anymore.